# Byobu - modify/pass environment variable in existing session on reattach

Tags: bash, tmux, byobu

I'm experimenting with waypipe recently. I'm creating remote window like this:

```
waypipe -c lz4=9 ssh user@host foot
```

On creating new foot window waypipe denpends on environment variable $WAYLAND_DISPLAY. Each new pipe creates it's own variable:

```
$ env | grep WAYLAND_DISPLAY
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-BoN0JMLL
```

Now... on first time launching byobu I can pass this variable like this:

```
$(env | grep WAYLAND_DISPLAY) byobu
```

but I can't imagine how could I change it for existing byobu session or at least make byobu to inherit this variable from terminal session you currently on. Is there any way to achieve this?

setenv -g not quite working.

setenv -g sorta works, but only for new windows/sessions

Answer (score 0):

> Now... on first time launching byobu I can pass this variable like this:

You don't need that. All that the `$(env) byobu` trick does is copy the variable from the environment into...the...environment. That already happens by default when you run a command – indeed that's how *'env' itself* receives the variable in the first place.

> setenv -g sorta works, but only for new windows/sessions

That's unfortunately the nature of environment variables. Each process has a **copy** of its parent's environment variables, and that copy cannot be changed from outside. Even though byobu (tmux) itself knows the new environment variables and can provide them to *newly started* shells in new windows, there's really nothing it can do about processes that are already running: they have the environment that they have.

So in addition to using `setenv`, you need to tweak your shell to explicitly **pull** the variable out of `tmux showenv` before every command, *or* make wrapper scripts (or aliases, functions) so that they pull the variable whenever you run the GUI apps that you commonly use.

(For example, the former could probably be achieved through zsh's precmd or similar.)